# Groupby - count of pandas df with duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count

I am trying to perform a `groupby` `count` of a pandas `df` with duplicate values. I'm hoping to return the unduplicated values only. For the intended output, I only want to determine the count of values between `Val_A` and `Val_B`. The returned column can be labelled anything as I will rename it. For the purposes of this question, I'll label it `Val_X`

```
d = ({
    'Date' : ['1/2/18','1/2/18','1/2/18','1/2/18','1/2/18','1/2/18'],
    'Val_A' : [1,1,2,2,1,1],           
    'Val_B' : ['X','X','X','X','Y','Y'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Date'],values=['Val_A','Val_B'],aggfunc= 'count')
```

Output:

```
            Val_A  Val_B
    Date                
    1/2/18      6      6
```

Intended Output:

```
            Val_X 
    Date             
    1/2/18      3
```

Comment: Could you explain the logic how you got your intended output? Are you counting the unique values per date per column?

Comment: @Erfan, there are 6 values in each column in related to the specified date. However, when grouping both `Val_A` and `Val_B`, there are only 3 independent values. As in, non-duplicate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop duplicates and pass on Val_B as values,

```
pd.pivot_table(df.drop_duplicates(), index=['Date'],values=['Val_B'],aggfunc= 'count')

        Val_B
Date    
1/2/18  3
```

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you get it through

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df.drop_duplicates(), index=['Date'],values=['Val_A','Val_B'],aggfunc= 'count')
```

However, your example numbers are not the same.

```
df.drop_duplicates()

     Date  Val_A Val_B
0  1/2/18      1     X
2  1/2/18      2     X
4  2/2/18      1     Y
6  2/2/18      2     Y
```

Comment: That works @Gwang-Jin Kim. I've overthought this I think. I can just drop the unwanted column and rename the remaining

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to return the unique combinations in columns `Val_A` and `Val_B` for each group in `Date`:

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'Val_A', 'Val_B']).size().reset_index()

     Date  Val_A Val_B  0
0  1/2/18      1     X  2
1  1/2/18      1     Y  2
2  1/2/18      2     X  2
```

If you want the size:

```
g = df.groupby(['Date', 'Val_A', 'Val_B'])

len(g)

# Out
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.drop_duplicates().groupby('Date').Val_A.count().reset_index(name='Val_x')


Out[1996]:
     Date  Val_x
0  1/2/18      3
```